# mysql pdo: how to detect if a statement made an insert or updated a preexisting row

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am using a statement in the format:

```
insert into $table (field, value) values (:name, :value)
on duplicate key
update value=:value2 into $table (field, value) values (:name, :value)
```

to update or insert a line into my database (with a unique constraint), but I have several other queries to make and which one should be used depends on whether data has been inserted or updated. Is there a way in PDO to detect which has occurred?

Comment: Though syntax you are using seems unusual. Are you sure you want second `into` part? Also your query is vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: @Your Common Sense: "Also your query is vulnerable to SQL injection" --- it's just a guess :-) If `$table` is whitelisted then it's fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if
>   the row is inserted as a new row, and 2 if an existing row is updated.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, rowCount will return 1 on insert and 2 on update.